# Solve this Trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am not quite good at maths, so can you help me ?

$$\tan x + 2 \cot x - 3=0$$

Comment: What exactly do you want? $\tan (x) + 2 \cot(x)-3$? And what do you want to solve for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\tan{x}=\frac{1}{\cot{x}}.$$ 
$$\tan{x}+2 \cdot \frac{1}{\tan{x}}-3=0.$$
make a notation $t=\tan{x}. $

Comment: @Bee:  If this was sufficient to get you to a solution, you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside it.